# Вывод всех подпапок в выбранной папке

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Добрый день, как получить имена всех папок, находящихся в выбранной мной директории?
Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dir.entries(".").select {|f| File.directory? f}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помог!